# What's the difference between errors and failures in JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm learning to use JUnit.

Some of my tests have come up as "errors" and some as "failures". What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 13):

An **error** is when something breaks and an exception occurs, such as a Null object reference.

A **failure** is when the test criteria is not met. i.e. when the `Assert()` fails.

[This is in general, not just junit.]

Answer (score 4):

In simple words,

**Errors** - mean that while your test was running, there were some unhandled/unforeseen exceptions, and hence, your test case basically crashed without executing fully.

**Failures** - mean that your test completed successfully, but the test condition of your test criteria has failed(not what you expected it to be).

Answer (score 2):

A **failure** is when one of your assertions fails--that is, your program does something wrong, and your JUnit test notices and reports the fact.

An **error** is when some other Exception occurs--one you haven't tested for and didn't expect, such as a NullPointerException or an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2):

**Failure** - When test case fails (Condition that you assert did not succeed)

**Error** - Unexpected scenarios or errors in executing the test case